# PHP path not found in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I need help to set my executable Path of PHP8.1 in VS Code.

I've got this error from PHP Intelephense :

"Cannot validate since /usr/bin/php8.1 is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable."

But as you can see on the screenshot all is setup like required... But it doesn't work !

[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot contains :

- whereis php command result
- settings.json of VSCode
- PHP Intelephense extension error

Thank's for help.

Comment: PHP Intelephense doesn't use that directive and, in fact, [Quick Start](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client#quick-start) instructions ask you to disable it. Also, nothing in your pictures indicate that you have a PHP interpreter in that path.

Comment: Yeah in the screenshot you find `/usr/bin/php` but not `/usr/bin/php8.1`. Change the setting to `/usr/bin/php` then?

Comment: I tried with /usr/bin/php8.1 because /usr/bin/php was not working :|
Same problem with /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

Your php path, as shown inyou whereis command result, is `/usr/bin/php`. Just modify your settings to change 'phpserver.phpPath' and 'php.validate.executablePath' to that.

Comment: I tried with /usr/bin/php8.1 because /usr/bin/php was not working, I've got the same error.
/usr/bin/php is just a symbolic link to /usr/bin/php8.1

Comment: Try to run "php --version" and see what happens.

Comment: Also "ls -l /usr/bin/php"